# How to get notified on window resize in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing an extension for the Chrome browser where I want to add an event listener for the window resize event.  My method is being executed for the window load event, but not being executed for the resize event.

Below is the code for my manifest.json file

```
{
  "name": "A browser action",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Below is the code for my background.js file.

```
var myExtension = 
{  
    init: function()
    {  
      // The event can be DOMContentLoaded, pageshow, pagehide, load or   unload.           
      alert("ASHSIH");
      window.addEventListener("resize", this.onmyPageResize, false);
    },
    onmyPageResize: function(aEvent) 
    {  
      alert("RESIZED");
                
    }  
}
  
  
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){  
  window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer   needed  
  myExtension.init();    
},false);
```

Comment: Did you try `document.addEventListener('resize', ...)`?

Comment: Have you tried not using `this` in your function variable identifier? It looks like you are using it correctly, but it adds an extra Thing That Can Go Wrong in your example. Your test case would be simpler without it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried both the ways but not getting the resize event called for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background.js file cannot capture resize events in the browser. You would need to inject a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I modified my manifest.json file to have one more field("content_scripts"), please see the code below for this file, neverthless I am not getting event listener getting called. Morever My load function message box itself is not coming now. Please advice where I am going wrong.        {
  "name": "My extension",
  "version": "12.0.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],

  "manifest_version": 2
 
}

Comment: Can you copy your window resize event code in a separate file instead of background.js. I am not 100% sure using the same file for both purposes is supported.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, I am able to achieve this by using content script only. And even I am able to put load and resize event listener in the same js file itself.  Thanks a lot once again. Following is the content for my working manifest.json file.    {
 "name": "Tile",
 "version": "1.2",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "Tile and stick windows without overlap.",
 "content_scripts": [
  {
   "js": ["chrome-o-tile.js"],
   "matches": [
    "<all_urls>"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "permissions": ["tabs"]
  
}

Answer (score 5):

[Chrome-o-Tile](https://github.com/NV/chrome-o-tile) is one example of an extension which listens resize in its content script.

In manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"
    ]
  }
],
```

In contentscript.js:

```
'use strict';

var timeoutId = 0;

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'resize'});
    timeoutId = 0;
  }, 100);
}, false);
```

In background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function requested(request) {
  if (request.method === 'resize') {
    ...
  }
)};
```

There is also an open issue to implement [chrome.windows.onResize event for Chrome extensions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44464).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this example. It really works. I am able to get the re size events..

Comment: Yes, thanks you so much for share your Chrome-o-Tile example, perfect answer

Comment: A `chrome.onBoundsChanged` event has been added as of  **Chrome 86** (dev channel as of time of writing) (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onBoundsChanged).

Answer (score 2):

For future readers of this question, the `chrome.windows` API provides an `onBoundsChanged` event:

> onBoundsChanged (Since Chrome 86)
>
> Fired when a window has been resized; this event is only dispatched when the new bounds are committed, and not for in-progress changes.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onBoundsChanged

This is how the event can be used: `chrome.windows.onBoundsChanged.addListener( callback() )`

(Make sure the `manifest.json` file declares the `tabs` permission)

```
  {
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `bind()` function.. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
//do something here
});
```

Comment: I tried this , but not helping me. I would appriciate if you can post some samples. Thanks a lot!