# CSS - Media Queries in a Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, media-queries, browser-extension

How can I properly do a media query on the Chrome window's width? Is it even possible to properly do media queries in a Chrome extension? 
Right now, my media queries act on the width of the extension's viewport, not on the actual browser's viewport (and the extension's viewport can be larger than the browser's). In a normal web app, the viewport width is always equivalent to the browser's viewport, but it doesn't seem to be the same for an extension

There seems to be a way to do this with JavaScript by setting the 'html' tag's width, but if there is a pure CSS way that'd be preferable

(This is for a browser action extension with a popup UI)

Comment: What kind of extension? An extension doesn't even have to have a UI. Where is that page with a viewport (bigger than the browser's window)?

Comment: A browser action can have a UI, it's a popup for the extension
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction

Comment: Ah. You should mention that. That's only a very small part of the chrome extension toolkit. The only part I know nothing about, I'm afraid =) Goodluck

Comment: Yep, did that as soon as you mentioned it. I thought it would be evident given I was talking about UIs. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Why do you want to know Chrome's "window width"? And by the way, there are more possibilities to have UI in an extension besides a page action or browser action, e.g. a `chrome-extension:`-URL in a tab/popup/iframe/infobar/desktop notification.

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear what you're asking. Which page are you querying in? In a popup, and you want the parent window's dimensions? It's certainly possible in JS and certainly impossible in CSS (since CSS would only see the popup window's own dimensions)

Comment: I'd like to know Chrome's window width so that I can implement some responsive design in my popup (if someone with a smaller screen is using it, for instance). I'm querying in my popup, and yes I did want the parent window's dimensions. I figured it might be impossible in CSS (unless with some Chrome specific CSS), but I thought I might ask in case it wasn't. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to still be an issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1230120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in a browser action popup, it is impossible to query the parent window's width with pure CSS. As I thought and @Xan confirmed in the comments, JavaScript is necessary to get the width of the parent window.

A way to do this with JavaScript can be found here: [How to get notified on window resize in chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141072/how-to-get-notified-on-window-resize-in-chrome-browser). Note that this does require a content script as chrome.window.onResized is still an open issue since 2010